# Find $c$ such that $6y=c+4x$ is normal to $y=8x^3 - 12x^2 +1$

Tags: coordinate-systems

> The equation of a curve is $y=8x^3 - 12x^2 +1$. Find the value of $c$ for which the line $6y=c+4x$ is a normal to the curve.

Help me please. I think there must be a point where the curve meets the line but I don't know how to find that point

Comment: Normal to which point of the curve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you tell us about your thoughts on the problem and what you've tried so far? We expect all questions to contain that information before we can give you a good answer. Again, welcome, and I hope that we're able to help you!

Comment: You have to enclose the MathJax in `$` signs in order for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate $y=8x^3 - 12x^2 +1 \ \ \ $

You get $\ \ \frac{dy}{dx}=24x^2-24x=24x(x-1) \ \ $  .

You can see that your line has slope $ \ \ 2 \over 3 \ \ $.  So ask when $ \ \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac 3 2 ?$  Solve for $x$ when $$\frac {-3} 2 = 24x^2-24x$$

There are two $x$ values that will satisfy.  They will each have a corresponding $y$ coordinate on the cubic which you can get by plugging in those $x$ values you solved for.  Then you will have a slope (your original slope of $2/3$) and two points, which you can make two lines with.   Then you can find $c$.

Comment: I got it. Many thanks to you. This is one of the questions in NUS entrance examination.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

This line has slope $\frac23$. If it intersects the cubic at some point and is normal to thtangent to the cubic at that point, the tangent will have slope $-\frac 32$. Hence you first have to find the points on the cubic at which $\;y'(x)=-\frac32$, then determine the corresponding value of $c$  from the equation of the normal.

Comment: Oh wow. Find out the point is the key to solve this problem. Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let the point at which the normal is drawn be $(t, 8t^3 - 12t^2 + 1)$

Since $y = 8x^3 - 12x^2 + 1$,

$-\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1} {24x (1-x)}$

At $x = t$, $-\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1} {24t (1-t)}$

Equation of the normal:

$y - (8t^3 - 12t^2 + 1) =   \frac{1} {24t (1-t)} (x-t)$

Now if the above equation is identical to $6y = c + 4x$, we must have

$\frac{6}{1} = \frac{4}{\frac{1}{24t (1-t)}} = \frac{c}{8t^3 - 12t^2 + 1 - \frac{1}{24(1-t)}}$

Solving, $t = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ and $c = \frac{1}{4}(-32 \pm 31 \sqrt{3})$

[Please check the calculations]